# How can I send a private message to others page from Java without any interactive dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messages

How can I send a private message to others page from Java without any interactive dialog? I am using Graph API FB.UI to send the message but it pops up a dialog to hit Send button.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The point is for a dialog to appear so that the user can interactively comply with sending the message.